# Insert into multiple tables connected by foreign keys

Tags: python, mysql

Suppose I have 3 tables like so:

```
artist
- artist_id   // primary key, autoincrement
- artist_name // varchar

album
- album_id    // primary key, autoincrement
- artist_id   // foreign key to artist.artist_id
- album_name  // varchar

song
- song_id     // primary key, autoincrement
- album_id    // foreign key to album.album_id
- song_name   // varchar
```

What would be the best way to insert a single song - and associated artist and album, into their corresponding tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to do it like this, with 3 `INSERT` statements and `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

```
INSERT INTO artist(artist_name) VALUES("Name");
INSERT INTO album(artist_id, album_name) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),"Album");
INSERT INTO song(album_id,song_name) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),"Song");
```